# What are the known attacks on $\phi$-hiding assumption? How to chose its parameters?

Tags: rsa, hardness-assumptions

$\phi$-hiding assumption states the following.

Sample 2 random primes $e_0$ and $e_1$ in the range $[5, 2^{\lambda/4}]$. Sample $N = pq$ of length $\lambda$ ($p$ and $q$ are large primes of length $0.5\lambda$) such that only one of $e_0$, $e_1$ divides $\phi(N) = (p-1).(q-1)$. If an poly-time adversary is given $e_b$ for a random bit b, he cannot tell whether $e_b$ divides $\phi(N)$ or not with advantage significantly greater than $0.5$.

1. What are the currently known attacks on this assumption?
2. Does it hold for any randomly chosen N?
3. Why should $e_0$ and $e_1$ be random primes? Are there any attacks if they are composite? Should $e_0$, $e_1$ be random? Can't they be fixed?
4. Why should $e_0$ and $e_1$ be chosen in the range $[5, 2^{\lambda/4}]$? Are there known attacks if they are less than $5$ or greater than $2^{\lambda/4}$.
5. In case $e$ divides $\phi(N)$, we say that "$N$ $\phi$-hides $e$". What does the phrase mean?
6. Is $\phi$-hiding equivalent to RSA?
7. For 256 bit security, I need to choose RSA modulus N to be 3072 bits long. If I am using $\phi$-hiding assumption instead of RSA, how long should  modulus N be?

Comment: Note that $\phi(N)$ for $N=pq$ is always divisible by 2 and 4 so it probably was more convenient to also exclude 3 than to write $\{3\}\cup [5,2^{\lambda/4}]$.

Comment: @SEJPM We can detect whether $3 | \phi(N)$ as well. We know that, either N = 2 mod 3 or N = 1 mod 3 with equal probability. If N = 2 mod 3, then p = 1 mod 3 and q = 2 mod 3 or vice-versa. Therefore, $3 | \phi(N)$.

Comment: 1. for proper choice of parameters, no better attack than factorization is known. 5. It means that $N$ has $e$ "encoded inside it", but hidden in $\phi(N)$. 6. No.